# Get the latest revision number from svn

Tags: svn, svnkit

I have created an SVN repository. I am committing the files using api's available in SVN Kit.

```
ourClientManager.getCommitClient().doCommit(paths, keepLocks, "", force, recursive);
```

Before doing this, i want to know if the file was modified by somebody else. I was trying to get the latest revision number or date from svn and compare with that on the file. But i am not able to get it. Can any one please let me know how i can identify the file was modified by some when else while i was working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine:

- "[svnkit: how to get latest revision number from SVN DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223554/svnkit-how-to-get-latest-revision-number-from-svn-db)" (to get the latest revision of a SVN repo)

```
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
SVNDirEntry entry = repository.info(".", -1);
System.out.println("Latest Rev: " + entry.getRevision());
```

with:

- "[Get previous modified revision of a file using svnkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462384/get-previous-modified-revision-of-a-file-using-svnkit)" (to get the current of past revisions of a file)

```
logEntry.getRevision();
```